docker build problems with git, pip, mvn
I have Windows and WSL2 in a network that enforces certificates and SSL aggressively. To use git, pip or mvn, I have to make user account changes to put the certificate file in the environment and trust some pip sites.  The central problem is that we have a self-signed certificate in our chain and it drives the pip and git servers crazy.
This causes a weird problem with Windows Docker-Desktop.  When mlflow tries to launch docker, I hit a fail when the build tries to use git, pip, or mvn.
I run
$ mlflow models build-docker -m "runs:/25432534435423/Clustering" -n myco_ml/myco_ml_cluster:20241007 --enable-mlserver

The first error is a git error:
Registered model 'pj-cluster' already exists. Creating a new version of this model...
Created version '16' of model 'pj-cluster'.
model_uri: runs:/bd938a4092d14ec4b61a7db95f549459/Clustering_Model
ml_info.model_uri:  runs:/bd938a4092d14ec4b61a7db95f549459/Clustering_Model
2024/10/09 10:32:42 INFO mlflow.models.flavor_backend_registry: Selected backend for flavor 'python_function'
2024/10/09 10:32:42 INFO mlflow.pyfunc.backend: Building docker image with name hrb_mll_cluster
[+] Building 2.8s (8/21)                                                                                                                                                                docker:desktop-linux  => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                    0.1s  => => transferring dockerfile: 2.58kB                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s  => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04                                                                                                                                         1.9s  => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s  => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s  => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s  => => transferring context: 3.27kB                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s  => [ 1/17] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04@sha256:6d8d9799fe6ab3221965efac00b4c34a2bcc102c086a58dff9e19a08b913c7ef                                                                                 0.0s  => => resolve docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04@sha256:6d8d9799fe6ab3221965efac00b4c34a2bcc102c086a58dff9e19a08b913c7ef                                                                                   0.0s  => CACHED [ 2/17] RUN apt-get -y update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive TZ=Etc/UTC apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends wget curl nginx ca-certificates bzip2 build-essential cmake git-core   0.0s  => CACHED [ 3/17] RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive TZ=Etc/UTC apt-get -y install tzdata     libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev wget curl llvm     libncursesw5-dev xz-  0.0s  => ERROR [ 4/17] RUN git clone     --depth 1     --branch $(git ls-remote --tags --sort=v:refname https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv.git | grep -o -E 'v[1-9]+(\.[1-9]+)+$' | tail -1)     https://github  0.7s ------
 > [ 4/17] RUN git clone     --depth 1     --branch $(git ls-remote --tags --sort=v:refname https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv.git | grep -o -E 'v[1-9]+(\.[1-9]+)+$' | tail -1)     https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv.git /root/.pyenv:
0.655 fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv.git/': server certificate verification failed. CAfile: none CRLfile: none
0.662 fatal: repository '/root/.pyenv' does not exist
------
Dockerfile:10
--------------------
   9 |         libncursesw5-dev xz-utils tk-dev libxml2-dev libxmlsec1-dev libffi-dev liblzma-dev
  10 | >>> RUN git clone \
  11 | >>>     --depth 1 \
  12 | >>>     --branch $(git ls-remote --tags --sort=v:refname https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv.git | grep -o -E 'v[1-9]+(\.[1-9]+)+$' | tail -1) \
  13 | >>>     https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv.git /root/.pyenv
  14 |     ENV PYENV_ROOT="/root/.pyenv"
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c git clone     --depth 1     --branch $(git ls-remote --tags --sort=v:refname https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv.git | grep -o -E 'v[1-9]+(\\.[1-9]+)+$' | tail -1)
  https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv.git /root/.pyenv" did not complete successfully: exit code: 128

View build details: docker-desktop://dashboard/build/desktop-linux/desktop-linux/nizz1fi7b3qbmu2dlf87mny06
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\A1146108\tmp\mlflow-01\cluster-02.py", line 56, in <module>
    mlflow.models.build_docker(
  File "C:\Users\A1146108\venv-mlflow-3.9\lib\site-packages\mlflow\models\python_api.py", line 86, in build_docker
    get_flavor_backend(model_uri, docker_build=True, env_manager=env_manager).build_image(
  File "C:\Users\A1146108\venv-mlflow-3.9\lib\site-packages\mlflow\pyfunc\backend.py", line 369, in build_image
    docker_utils.build_image_from_context(context_dir=cwd, image_name=image_name)
  File "C:\Users\A1146108\venv-mlflow-3.9\lib\site-packages\mlflow\models\docker_utils.py", line 230, in build_image_from_context
    raise RuntimeError("Docker build failed.")
RuntimeError: Docker build failed.

I went into the source code for mlflow and found that git call and hacked it so that git ignores certificates. Embarrassing, but workable.  After that, the git call succeeds but eventually build fails at the calls to pip. I go hack the source code again and ignore pip certificates. Again, embarrassing, but works.  Then "mvn", and hack that. I expect that if I keep hacking the mlflow source code to disable SSL checks at every step, it will eventually succeed.
This is ridiculous, though.  This cannot be what mlflow or Docker intend. Why don't other people crash into this? It seems, well, awful.
What am I missing?
I know Docker can build within WSL2 itself, if I uninstall Windows Docker-Desktop entirely. I followed these instructions: https://dataedo.com/docs/installing-docker-on-windows-via-wsl and the Docker build succeeded.  I'm pretty sure it is using my user environment, which has settings in .bashrc, and .config\git and .config\pip.
I'd like to cut mlflow's docker build code out of the workflow, at least then I'd see how to more easily customize the Docker file.

Why do you need pyenv instead of starting from a specific python base image? When will you need to manage or install other python versions at runtime without rebuilding the image?

mlflow decides that, it chooses pyenv.  I agree it seems unnecessary. But even getting past that, I've still got pip and mvn cert problems

Can you please share the full build log rather than line 10 onwards? Then error with the run command generally appears before it

I don't know for sure if this should be seen as an Mlflow problem or a Docker problem.  Or both.  I started an issue in the mlflow tracker. https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/issues/13359. IIn there, I have patch files to show the changes in mlflow to get past those (ignore certificates).

Looks like ca-certificates or some similar package should be updated in the container. Or, your ISP / proxy is not trusting  python.org (you are correct that it is an SSL problem). As mentioned, pyenv isn't really needed. If they built from a Python base image, then Python would already be installed in the container.
